# Replace variable with the path of the current location of where I am running

Tags: bash

In my bash script, I'd like to replace the part of the filename with the path of the current location of where I am running the script in.

```
#!/bin/bash
$MY_SPECIAL_FILE="$(pwd)/hello.txt
```

Currently, when I `echo $MY_SPECIAL_FILE`, it always prints out the initial pwd I was in, regardless of where I echo this from.

I want this to print out banana/hello.txt if I am in the banana directory, and apple/hello.txt if I am in the apple directory.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: the code you show is broken, so we don't know what you actually mean

Comment: provide code we can run to demonstrate the problem - [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: For shell scripts ALL_UPPERCASE_NAMES are generally reserved for shell and environment variables. `my_special_file=...` is fine.

Comment: Since the code you posted, is syntactically not correct, we can't discuss it. Please make code free of errors before posting. As for setting your variable, the simplest way would be `MY_SPECIAL_FILE=$PWD/hello.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently, when I `echo $MY_SPECIAL_FILE`, it always prints out the initial pwd I was in, regardless of where I echo this from.

Well, yes. In the shell, the value you assign to a variable is expanded at the time of the assignment. When you later expand the variable, you get whatever value was set.  If you want something different, you want the value to change then you must perform a new assignment.

Moreover, parameter expansion is not recursive, so even if you arranged your quoting so that `$(pwd)` was not expanded at the time you assigned your value to `MY_SPECIAL_FILE`, it *also* would not be expanded when you expanded the variable.  You would get the literal string "`$(pwd)`".

Possibly you are looking for a shell *function*, instead:

```
my_special_file() {
  echo "$(pwd)/hello.txt"
}
```

You would then execute that as a command:

```
$ my_special_file
/home/me/hello.txt
$ cd subdir
$ my_special_file
/home/me/subdir/hello.txt
```

And you can, of course, capture the output of that command so as to use it similarly to a variable:

```
$ cat "$(my_special_file)"
Hello, World from /home/me/subdir !
```